How to seal between PVC fascia board and roof shingles?
I have noticed a gap between PVC fascia board and roof shingles. I am worried that some small animals like mice could get in. It's hard to see the gap because of the shade, however I marked it with orange line. I was wondering if this is a gap I should seal? If so, what kind for material I can use to seal between PVC board and roof shingles. Photo was taking right after a rain so it looks wet.


That geometry seems peculiar. It looks like drainage frmo that valley just bypasses the gutter?

Gutters are ok. There is another gutter right under the gutter at 90 degree. About underneath the gutter two walls meet at 90 degrees. If the site allows I will upload another photo.
